# UI command *previous* to async task does not work if async task is enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, wpf-controls

I must not grasp async stuff as good as I thought because this has had me scratching my head for a couple of hours now.

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. Switch UI to "Fetching data..."
2. Fetch data with an async call
3. Present final results based on async call

I have the following callback from my WPF button in my view

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GeneratorButton.IsEnabled = false;
        ResultMsg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //default text of "Fetching data..."
        string tickersString = Tickers.Text;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tickersString))
        {
            tickersString = tickersString.ToUpper();
            string[] tickers = tickersString.Split(',', ' ');

            var stockGeneratorTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => GetStockDataAndGenerateCSV(tickers).Result);

            var allTasks = new Task[] { stockGeneratorTask };
            var tasksHandler = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(allTasks, completedTasks =>
            {
                return stockGeneratorTask.Result;
            });

            if (tasksHandler.Result)
            {
                ResultMsg.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
                ResultMsg.Text = "Your report was successfully generated.";
            }
            else
            {
                ResultMsg.Text = "There was an error while generating your report. Please try again later.";
                ResultMsg.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }

        GeneratorButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

My expectations where that as soon as the user hits the button they'd see the default text of "fetching data..." due to the visibility property switch. What's happening, from what I understand, is that the program is going straight to the async task, and when it comes back it shows the success (or error) message, but it skips the "fetching data..." altogether UNLESS I comment out the code from the declaration of stockGeneratorTask down (no async call happening).

Now, if this visibility switch is happening before the async task gets triggered, shouldn't I see this change before it goes to actually make the async call? Why am I only seeing it after it comes back?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something... you'd just want to change your method def to `private async void Button_Click`, get rid of everything between your `tickers` declaration and the `if` statement, and change the `if` to: `if(await GetStockDataAndGenerateCSV(tickers)) ...`. The way you're doing it now (accessing the `Result` property of the task without awaiting it) is blocking (i.e. not async).

Comment: Your code is all synchronous. Do not use `Task.Factory.StartNew` unless you [know exactly what you are doing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers are the one exception that allow for `async void`. Consider making the event handler async all the way and not mixing blocking calls like `.Result` which could lead to deadlocks. Assuming `GetStockDataAndGenerateCSV` returns `Task<bool>` then it should be awaited.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    GeneratorButton.IsEnabled = false;
    ResultMsg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //default text of "Fetching data..."
    var tickersString = Tickers.Text;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tickersString)) {
        tickersString = tickersString.ToUpper();
        string[] tickers = tickersString.Split(',', ' ');
        if (await GetStockDataAndGenerateCSV(tickers)) {
            ResultMsg.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
            ResultMsg.Text = "Your report was successfully generated.";
        } else {
            ResultMsg.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            ResultMsg.Text = "There was an error while generating your report. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    GeneratorButton.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)